# Handle cHash validation for pages with access restriction

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

The page `/my/page/subpage/detail/15` has an access restriction. User "HasAccess" can visit the page, whereas user "NoAccess" will keep the URL `/my/page/subpage/detail/15` but will see the content of the first page up the root line that has no access restriction: `/my/page`.

This works well on pages without custom parameters, e.g. standard pages where the only parameter is `id=123` because then no cHash is calculated.

With custom parameters however there is(!) a cHash in the decoded URL but it gets compared against a calculated cHash using the fallback pid of `/my/page` and not the original pid of `/my/page/subpage/`.

The only options seems to be a global setting:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFoundOnCHashError'] = 0;
```

Is there no other option?

Comment: Try first without realurl and see if it works. I am quite sure it will not work without realurl either.